# Android, listView items & ColorStateList

Tags: android, listview, colors

Remember the ColorStateList xml? by which you specify to a view use this color if you are in this state:

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:color="hex_color"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
```

How do I enforce by code: "Hey view! You are now in this state! Display accordingly!!" ??

My problem is with a listview. I want a child to appear as clicked/selected, and neither of this lines seem to do the work:

```
m_listView.getChildAt(0).requestFocus();
m_listView.getChildAt(0).setPressed(true);
```

Comment: i wanted by code to ask a child view of a listview to display it's self as selected (or pressed..) anyways this was the solution: m_listView.setItemChecked(0, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this..
Solution was:

m_ItemsListView.setItemChecked(0, true);